# Drop non-unique variables

Tags: r, sorting, filter, data.table, data-cleaning

suppose i have a tibble:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  PD          Var                                       P  R.sq
  <chr>       <chr>                                 <dbl> <dbl>
1 CommercialB Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases  -0.473  1   
2 CommercialB HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC2           2.15   0.9 
3 CommercialB HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC3          -0.352  0.5 
4 CommercialB HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC4           0.640  0.4 
5 CommercialB HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC1           0.587  0.3 
6 CommercialB Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases1  1.14   0.2 
7 CommercialB Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases4 -0.437  0.08
8 CommercialB Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases3  2.32   0.06
9 CommercialB Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases2 -0.273  0.01
```

My question is:
how can i extract one name from each group of the Var Column?

I have tried using `distinct()` but still returned the full data. Im not sure how to tell R know that I want the output to be a vector that returns the names in `Vars` which have the highest `R.sq` value. For example the output would read:

```
>c(tib$Var['Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases'],tib$Var['HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC2'])
```

I will later use the output to transform a much larger df, where the column names match the row entries for `Var`
Can someone Please Help me?

```
tib <- structure(list(PD = c("CommercialB", "CommercialB", "CommercialB", 
"CommercialB", "CommercialB", "CommercialB", "CommercialB", "CommercialB", 
"CommercialB"), Var = c("HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC4", "HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC3", 
"HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC2", "HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC1", 
"Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases4", "Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases3", 
"Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases2", "Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases1", 
"Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases"), P = c(0.639854267828088, 
-0.352112247223695, 2.14688262893268, 0.586980189852499, -0.437388302395368, 
2.3210132561933, -0.272751224405276, 1.13554334651023, -0.473126862945436
), R.sq = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.9, 0.3, 0.08, 0.06, 0.01, 0.2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: Could you please post the tibble in your question rather than the table version; dput() is helpful in this respect

Comment: How are you defining a 'group' in Var?

Comment: Is the first group: 'HealthInsuranceCoverage' or 'HealthInsuranceCoverage'.SC? what about the second group? is this 'Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases' or just 'Charge'

Comment: @peter I did group_by(...., Var) and yes the second group would be the full Charge.offRates.TotalLoansAndLeases

Comment: Then just dput(head(tibble, 20))

Comment: I'm sorry I've had a look at what you sent: this seems to be grouped already. Have you looked at [MRE] to see how to produce a question with a dataframe so that you can help others to help you. You may have to set out the dataframe manually rather than just copy from the durrent dataframe, they may not be a bad thing as it focus the mind on what is important and better understandin the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option using `data.table`:

```
setDT(DF)[DF[, .I[which.max(v4)], .(v1, gsub("\\d+$", "", v2))]$V1]
```

data:

```
DF <- structure(list(v1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("g1", "g3"), class = "factor"), v2 = structure(1:10, .Label = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C1", "C2"), class = "factor"), 
    v3 = structure(c(9L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("-0.713778796788462", 
    "-1.08665755420174", "-2.20874190923613", "0.226184032935989", 
    "0.228687166237024", "0.641078999902449", "0.659864898007848", 
    "1.11077415422586", "1.30243501910073", "1.57605315010293"
    ), class = "factor"), v4 = structure(c(6L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 
    8L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 3L), .Label = c("-0.206875175346852", "-0.263652840400634", 
    "-0.563443803887212", "-0.605033653912397", "-1.10776531137661", 
    "-1.17580991422538", "-1.2693304626523", "-1.27119461040557", 
    "0.143314307415803", "0.388467088361395"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: is there a way to get the first (highest v4) for each of the A's ,B's, C's in v2, while keeping the number on the end.. for example since a2 has a higher v4 than a1 how can i get a vector that returns "A2","B1","C2"

Comment: @JeraldAchaibar i have edited the code to address that. Not in front of computer to generate the output though

Comment: spot on. Nice simple use of DT

Answer (score 0):

You could `group_by` `PD` and remove digits from `Var` and select `max` row with `R.sq`.

```
library(dplyr)

tib %>% group_by(PD, Var = sub('\\d+$', '', Var)) %>% slice(which.max(R.sq))

#   PD          Var                                    P  R.sq
#  <chr>       <chr>                                <dbl> <dbl>
#1 CommercialB Charge.OffRates.TotalLoansAndLeases -0.473   1  
#2 CommercialB HealthInsuranceCoverage.SC           2.15    0.9
```

If you want few columns, you can `select` them.